# Can not connect to oracle outside docker container

Tags: oracle, docker, oracle-sqldeveloper, docker-for-windows, oracle19c

I have create an image for the oracle 19c. I have started my container with below command.

`docker run --name oracledb -d -p 1527:1521 -p 5700:5500 -e ORACLE_PWD=password1 -e ORACLE_CHARACTERSET=AL32UTF8 -v /d/docker-code/oracle-data oracle/database:19.3.0-ee`

After creation of container, I am able to login in the container. I am able to connect with the below command inside the container.

**sqlplus system/password1@172.17.0.2:1527/ORCLCDB**

Outside of the container, from the cmd, I can not connect to that oracle instance.

**Note: I have already installed oracle on the windows machine at port 1521 which is default port.**

**listener.ora**

```
LISTENER =
(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.17.0.2)(PORT = 1527))
  )
)

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = ORCLCDB)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1)
      (SID_NAME = ORCLCDB)
    )
   )


DEDICATED_THROUGH_BROKER_LISTENER=OFF
DIAG_ADR_ENABLED = off
```

**tnsnames.ora**

```
ORCLCDB=172.17.0.2:1527/ORCLCDB
ORCLPDB1=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.17.0.2)(PORT = 1527))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORCLPDB1)
    )
  )
```

I am not able to connect from SQL Developer or from CMD. I am able to get timeout error when I am trying to access outside of the docker container.

```
ERROR:
ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
```

Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you add `172.17.0.2` in your Windows network IPs? I mean can you ping `172.17.0.2`?

Comment: ``172.17.0.2`` I can not ping this ip. I do not have added in Windows network IPs. How can I add this?

Comment: Run Command Prompt program as an Administrator, then run `ipconfig` to see if it exists. I'm not familiar enough with Docker in Windows, but in Linux it adds.

Comment: Your container port is 1527 hence: -p [host_port]:[container_port] -> -p 1521:1527. but since 1521 is already taken, make is something else -> -p 1522:1527. Now you can connect:sqlplus system/password1@localhost:1522/ORCLCDB

Comment: @BjarteBrandt - Do I need to change something in the docker file or while creating image for oracle 19c? As of now I have changed port value from 1521 to 1527 while creating docker image.

With the change you have suggest, I am still not able to connect outside of the container. 

Inside the docker container, I am able to connect with this, 
`sqlplus system/password1@localhost:1527/ORCLCDB`
But outside the docker container, I am not able to connect with this, 
`sqlplus system/password1@localhost:1522/ORCLCDB`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure all container network interfaces are listening for database traffic, hence `0.0.0.0`. Do not hardcode a docker bridge network address (172..) because this address will be assigned at container startup. Just stick with the default port 1521 local to the container. This port - 1521 - is local to the container and not exposed to the host OS. You publish this port to the host OS where you decide which port to use, hence `-p 1522:1521`

```
LISTENER =
(DESCRIPTION_LIST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
  )
)
```

Now you can fire up the container on your host OS by issuing:

```
docker run --name oracledb -d -p 1522:1521 -p 5700:5500 -e ORACLE_PWD=password1 -e ORACLE_CHARACTERSET=AL32UTF8 -v /d/docker-code/oracle-data oracle/database:19.3.0-ee
```

This should now work

```
sqlplus system/password1@localhost:1522/ORCLCDB
```

Tip. You can now pull Oracle XE 18c from Docker Hub. I recommend you to test this image if you still cannot connect using the image you have built.

```
docker run -d -p 1522:1521 --rm -e ORACLE_PASSWORD=Welcome_1 -v oracle-volume:/opt/oracle/oradata gvenzl/oracle-xe

docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE              COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS             PORTS                    NAMES
97ce7cd3d7ca   gvenzl/oracle-xe   "container-entrypoin…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour   0.0.0.0:1522->1521/tcp   elegant_borg

sqlplus system/Welcome_1@localhost:1522/XE

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon May 31 10:21:18 2021
Version 19.8.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Mon May 31 2021 10:20:19 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.4.0.0.0

system@XE> set echo on
system@XE> @pdbs
system@XE>
system@XE> col con_id format 999
system@XE> col dbid format 99999999999999999
system@XE> col name format a30
system@XE> col open_mode format a10
system@XE> col open_time format a38
system@XE>
system@XE> select p1.con_id, p1.dbid, p1.name, p2.status, p1.open_mode, p1.open_time
  2  from
  3    v$pdbs p1 join dba_pdbs p2 on (p1.con_id = p2.con_id);

CON_ID               DBID NAME                           STATUS     OPEN_MODE  OPEN_TIME
------ ------------------ ------------------------------ ---------- ---------- --------------------------------------
     2         1957965804 PDB$SEED                       NORMAL     READ ONLY  31.05.2021 06:54:00474 AM +00:00
     3         4267393270 XEPDB1                         NORMAL     READ WRITE 31.05.2021 06:54:01229 AM +00:00

2 rows selected.

system@XE>
```

Best of luck!

Comment: I was trying to connect to port inside docker, your comment "This port - 1521 - is local to the container and not exposed to the host OS" helped me, thanks!